# Почему не устанавливаются поля объекту через SELECT запрос к MySQL в Java

Tags: java, sql

Ошибок никаких не выдаёт, просто возвращает null.
Query, посылаемый в базу данных, предполагается в виде Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Login = "Login" AND Password = 12345;

**Метод, в котором посылается SELECT запрос.**

```
public static Human authorization(String login, int password, Human human){
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Login = \"" + login + "\" AND Password = " + password + ";";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                human.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
                human.setAge(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Age")));
                human.setWeight(Float.parseFloat(rs.getString("Weight")));
                human.setHeight(Float.parseFloat(rs.getString("Height")));
                human.setCcal(Float.parseFloat(rs.getString("Ccal")));
                human.setLogin(rs.getString("Login"));
                human.setPassword(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Password")));
                human.setGender(rs.getString("Gender"));
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException error) {
            return null;
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return human;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите точный текст запроса, полученный в переменной `query`. Заодно учтите - для обрамления строковых литералов нужно использовать одинарную кавычку, двойная порой используется для других целей.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать в запросе одинарные ' ' кавычки вместо двойных " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решила запись columnId вместо columnName в параметры getString().
Не знаю, почему не работало с columnName, но проблема решена.